# Overriding RSpec generator template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

Trying override the default rspec-rails scaffold generator template for controllers but for some reason the new template isn't getting picked up

```
/lib/templates/rspec/scaffold/controller_spec.rb
```

Apparently putting it there should just work but it still doesn't show when running `rails g rspec:scaffold`.

Did the format change? I'm using Rails 4.2.2 and rspec-rails 3.3.3

Comment: When you say "there" you're referring to an absolute path. Am I right in assuming that the `lib` is actually located inside your `app` folder?

Comment: Yup sorry, I mean inside the app folder

Comment: @user3598395 Were you able to solve this? /lib/templates/rspec/scaffold/controller_spec.rb is supposed to be the correct path, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @dwhite Nope, gave up in the end

Answer (score 1):

A quick search on google revealed this one: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/rspec/scaffold/templates/controller_spec.rb

Which lives under `lib/generators/spec/scaffold/templates/controller_spec.rb`. Perhaps your source for the location is wrong?

Comment: still doesnt seem to work, heres a bunch of other ones I've tried.

`webapp/lib/generators/rspec/scaffold/templates/controller_spec.rb`
`webapp/lib/rspec/scaffold/controller_spec.rb`
`webapp/lib/templates/generators/rspec/scaffold/controller_spec.rb`
`webapp/lib/templates/rspec/scaffold/controller_spec.rb`
`webapp/lib/templates/rails-rspec/scaffold/controller_spec.rb`
`webapp/lib/templates/rails-rspec/rspec/scaffold/controller_spec.rb`